# JSF components API url

Tags: jsf-2

Does anyone have the URL to the Mojara JSF 2 components API.

I seem to have lost it and cannot seem to find them via Oracle's site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as "components API". Perhaps you meant the JSF 2 tag library documentation?

The JSF 2.x tag library documentations are available here:

- JSF 2.0: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/
- JSF 2.1: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant...it's been a long day! Thanks BalusC.